# nginx rule for limiting access based on url

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to setup a rule in nginx where I will deny traffic if a certain url is accessed from outside the specified ip address range.  Instead of specifying the url pattern that needs to be protected, I would like to setup a rule that would essentially say the following:
if URL is not a certain url format, apply the deny/allow rules in a permissions.conf file.

**Previously I had this (which seems to work):**

```
location ^~ /admin {
   include permissions.conf file
}
```

**permissions.conf file**

```
  allow 127.0.0.1;
   deny all;
```

I would now like to replace the rule above and specify a rule which only gets hit if the url is not of a certain pattern (so in the case below, if it is not /a/test, then it should apply the permissions.conf file.  The format below is not working - any ideas on how to fix it?

```
location ~ (/a\/(?!test)) {
    include permissons.conf
}
```

I tried this as well:

```
location ~ (/a/(?!test)) {
    include permissons.conf
}
```

&

```
location ~* ^(?!/a/test/) {
    include permissons.conf
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
location / {
   if ($request_uri !~ "^/a/test$")
   {
     include permissons.conf
   }
}
```